# Haproxy still dispatches connections to backend server when it's graceful restarting

Tags: haproxy

We are using haproxy for thrift(rpc) server load balancing in tcp mode. But we've encountered one problem when backend server restarts.

When our thrift(rpc) server restarts, it first stop listening on the port which haproxy is configured to connect, but will still process running requests until they are all done(graceful restart).

So during restarting period, there are still connected sockets made from client to backend server via haproxy while backend server is not accepting any new connections, but haproxy still treats this backend server as healthy, and will dispatch new connections to this server. Any new connections dispatched to this server will take quite a long time to connect, and then timeout.

Is there any way to notify haproxy that server has stop listening and not to dispatch any connection to it?

I've tried following:

1. `timeout connect` set to very low + `redispatch` + `retry 3`
2. `option tcp-check`

Both not solve the problem.